# Looking for reverse engneer online course

Tags: ida, windows, linux, patch-reversing

I looking for online reverse engeneer  course.

Course that study ida,reverse and patch for windows/ linux.

Working with ida and another tool.

I like many videos lesons.

Do you know one?

Comment: did you tried googling? you're not even giving us what level you're interested in (entry, intermediate, advanced).

Comment: Also be aware that those courses most likely will be in highly technical English – beyond your current level.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you like videos, here's a handful of excellent resources off the top of my head:

**OpenSecurityTraining's courses**: http://opensecuritytraining.info/Training.html

**Sam Bowne's CNIT series**: https://www.youtube.com/user/sambowne/videos

**MalwareAnalysisForHedgehogs** (not a course, but extremely valuable, modern videos): https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVFXrUwuWxNlm6UNZtBLJ-A

**OALabs** (also not a course, but awesome, modern videos): https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC--DwaiMV-jtO-6EvmKOnqg/videos

Comment: I looking for recommend on some course you tried

Comment: I've watched most videos from all of these resources, which is why I instantly recommended them.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Malware Analysis course at - https://github.com/RPISEC/Malware

Comment: maybe add a word of explanation why this one?